# VSTS enable to go back to old local workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

I am new to VS 2015 and VSTS
I tried to change my local workspace.First of all, I changed it from defaut "Path1" to "path2" but the project can't be loaded so I tried to go back to "Path1". 
WhenI click ok to save changes VS2015 still a very very long time without any response.
I tried to emty the cahce of TF folder under %appdata but it is not ok .
always I get path2 and I can't load the project in my local machine

[image]
after a very long time I get this error message
[image]
Pleaseeeee save my life !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this problem 
1) by cleaning the cahce of TF folder under %appdata/Local/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/6.0/Cache 

 
2) Removing the old local workspace and not edit the path

3)you should use an other path for your local folder.

4) get last version